# How do you assign a char from one char array to another char array in a loop in c?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write code that will read in morse code from one .txt file into a char array. I then read in a test file into another char array. From there I want to read the test file into morse code and print it to the monitor.

My input files are:

```
A.- B-... C-.- D-.. E. F.._. G--. H.... I.. J.--- K-.- L.-.. M-- N-. O--- P.--.
Q--.- R.-. S... T- U..- V...- W.-- X-..- Y-.-- Z--..

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

My .c code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int  i=0,j=0, n=0,x=0, SIZE=100;

    char SENTENCE[100][100];
    char morse[100][100];
    char fileName[SIZE];
    char SecondFile[SIZE];


    printf("Enter a file name\n");
    scanf("%s", fileName);

    FILE *file;  /*  FILE pointer  */
    file = fopen(fileName, "r");  /* open a text file for reading */


    while(fgets(morse[n++],20,file))
    {
    }


    for (i=0 ; i<n; i++)
    {
       printf("\n%s",  morse[i]);
    }


    printf("\n\nEnter a file name\n");
    scanf("%s", SecondFile);
    FILE *start;  /*  FILE pointer  */
    start = fopen(SecondFile, "r");  /* open a text file for reading */


    while(fgets(SENTENCE[j++],30,start))
    {
    }


    for (i=0 ; i<j; i++)
    {
       printf("\n%s",  SENTENCE[i]);
    }


    for (x=0; x<=SIZE; x++)                     
    {                                           
       if(SENTENCE[x]=='A'||SENTENCE[x]=='a')   
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);            
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='B'||SENTENCE[x]=='b') 
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='C'||SENTENCE[x]=='c')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='D'||SENTENCE[x]=='d')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='E'||SENTENCE[x]=='e')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='F'||SENTENCE[x]=='f')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='G'||SENTENCE[x]=='g')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='H'||SENTENCE[x]=='h')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='I'||SENTENCE[x]=='i')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='J'||SENTENCE[x]=='j')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='K'||SENTENCE[x]=='k')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='L'||SENTENCE[x]=='l')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='M'||SENTENCE[x]=='m')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='N'||SENTENCE[x]=='n')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='O'||SENTENCE[x]=='o')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='P'||SENTENCE[x]=='p')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='Q'||SENTENCE[x]=='q')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='R'||SENTENCE[x]=='r')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='S'||SENTENCE[x]=='s')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='T'||SENTENCE[x]=='t')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='U'||SENTENCE[x]=='u')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='V'||SENTENCE[x]=='v')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='W'||SENTENCE[x]=='w')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='X'||SENTENCE[x]=='x')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='Y'||SENTENCE[x]=='y')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='Z'||SENTENCE[x]=='z')
            printf("\n%s", morse[x]);
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='\0')
            printf("nothing read");
       else if(SENTENCE[x]=='.')
            printf("nothing read");
       else
        printf("error reading in a character from the file");

    }
    fclose(file);
    fclose(start);

    getch();
}
```

In the for loop above I'm trying to print the exact morse code equivalence. The only problem is I keep getting warnings when trying to compare the array `SENTENCE[x]` with a `ch`. Also is there anyway to assign certain characters from one char array to another char array in c. Is there a way I can do any of this? I'm currently writing the code in c.

Comment: remember your `SENTENCE` is 2D array

Comment: Just ask yourself, what is the type of `SENTENCE[x]` and what is the type of `ch`? Do you know how to work that out? In fact, the warning message will give you that info.

Comment: SENTENCE [X] points to a string that is 100 characters long.

Comment: You declared a two dimensional array. 100 strings each with 100 characters.

Comment: And assigning from one array to another is simply: `array1[i] = array2[i]`. If you want to copy the whole array then use `memcpy` in general and `strncpy` if the array contains a string.

Comment: And if you want a specific character: SENTENCE  [X][N] where N is zero based index to the character.

Comment: In fact since you only read in 20 or 30 characters per string you don't really need 100 chars per string. Maybe look up on string arrays and how to access them. I am also not sure why you need all the ifs. Use the istalpha test  to see if the character is A to Z.

Comment: It is probably good practice to scale down the 2d arrays. Is it possible to compare SENTENCE[X][N] with 'A'? I was getting a warning message "comparison between pointer and integer".

Comment: @kaylum only use `strncpy` if the destination is at least as big as the source. It does not correctly shorten strings to fit in smaller space.

Answer (score 1):

SENTENCE[x] does not return char, it returns char[]

remember that you defined SENTENCE as char[][]

Comment: I just wrote a test program an realized the difference. Sorry.